# Convolution of generalized hyperbolic distribution

Tags: distribution, random-variables

I have a question concerning the convolution of generalized hyperbolic distributions.
Proposition 6.13 of [McNeil, Embrechts, Frey](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/10496.html) states the following:

If $X$ has a $d$-dimensional generalized hyperbolic distribution
$$
X \sim GH_d(\lambda, \chi, \psi, \mu, \Sigma, \gamma),
$$
where $\lambda, \chi, \psi \in \Bbb R$, $\mu, \gamma \in \Bbb R^d$ and 
$\Sigma \in \Bbb R^{d \times d}$, 
then for $B \in \Bbb R^{k \times d}$ we have that

$$
BX \sim GH_k(\lambda, \chi, \psi, B\mu, B\Sigma B', B\gamma)
$$

As a special case of this proposition we get that the sum of two independent one- dimensional generalized hyperbolic distributions with the same parameters $\lambda, \chi, \psi$ has again a generalized hyperbolic distribution:
$$
X_i \sim  GH_1(\lambda, \chi, \psi, \mu_i, \sigma_i^2, \gamma_i) \implies X_1 + X_2 \sim GH_1(\lambda, \chi, \psi, \mu_1 + \mu_2, \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2, \gamma_1 + \gamma_2).
$$
This follows from taking $B = (1,1)$.

But numerical experiments show that this does not seem to be the case. Also  [in this article](http://jonaswallin.github.io/articles/2013/06/convolution-of-generalized-hyperbolic/) the author claims that only  certain sub distributions of the Generalized hyperbolic distribution are closed under convolution.

So there has to be something I am missing or getting wrong.
Any help is appreciated.